# xlsxwriter not being able to write to an excel file

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I was trying to make a basic data collector that will put information in excel and i was successful at doing so with the titles of the data sets but i cant figure out why it cant write the data entered into an excel file. Its far from done and i am fairly new to python (about a month into learning) so if my code looks terrible then my apologies but for any help thank you.

below is my full code and the error message along with it:

```
import xlsxwriter
import os
file = open("Datasheet.xlsx", "w+")
databook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Datasheet.xlsx")
data = databook.add_worksheet()

titles = []
masterdata = {}
data_entry = 0
data_filled = 0
project_start = True
while project_start == True:
    data_entires = input("How many data entries will you need? ")
    if data_entires.isdigit() == False:
        print("Sorry that is not a valid input please enter a numerical integer")
        project_start = True
    if data_entires.isdigit() == True:
        project_start = False

while int(data_entires) != data_entry:
    data_title = input("Please enter a title for a dataset ")
    titles.append(data_title)
    data_entry += 1

for value in range(len(titles)):
    data.write(0, value + 1, titles[value])

# dictionary with created lists for the amount of titles made
for i in range(len(titles)):
    dict = masterdata["list " + str(i + 1)] = []

for i in range(len(masterdata)):
    data_in = True
    while data_in == True:
        data = input(f"Please input data for {titles[i]} ")
        data_fill = masterdata["list " + str(i + 1)].append(data)
        fin = input("Do you want to input more data? ")
        if "yes" in fin:
            data_in = True
        if "no" in fin:
            data_in = False

lis = [list(x) for x in masterdata.values()]

for part in lis:
    l = list(str(part))

for value in l:
    data.write(value + 1, value + 1, l[value])


#os.startfile("Datasheet.xlsx")
#databook.close()
```

Error message : "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f'{filelocation}'", line 49, in 
data.write(value + 1, value + 1, l[value])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write' "

Comment: It looks like you overwrite the worksheet object called “data” with the string that you take in from “input()” and thus it isn’t a worksheet object anymore. The variable name “data” is probably a bad choice here since it isn’t descriptive and inadvertently caused an error in the program. Maybe stick with the conventional workbook/worksheet naming that is used in the XlsxWriter docs instead.

Comment: Good catch I am punching myself that i missed that thank you